# Taking screenshots of Java code from IDE to Latex (Text being to small)

Tags: documentation, coding

I have been trying to make the screenshot of my code fit the document better, where it fills from side to side, without being stretched as a "background"
Any idea of how to implement it? maybe change the documentclass etc?

as of now I am using figures

```
\begin{figure}[h]
\includegraphics[width=1.3\textwidth] /etc/etc
\end{figure}
```

but either its too small but centered, or too big and not centered while not filling both sides (the right side gets cut off if too big)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.se. Is there a particular reason you want to take screen shots? It might be better to include the code using the `listings` package or using `minted` instead. See [How best to include programming source code in LaTeX documents?](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/2037).

Comment: Yes, the current school project requires me to show a working system with the IDE (Should have specified it more clearly), thanks for the information though, will become useful later!
But as of now I am still a bit stuck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So there are two things going on here, what you think you want to do and what really you want to do.

**What you really want to do**

The `listings` package allows for pretty-printed Java (and other languages) code.

In your preamble:

```
\includepackage{listings}
\lstset{language=Java,basicstyle=\ttfamily} % see texdoc listings for more details on your options here
```

In your document:

```
\begin{lstlisting}
public CashDrawer put(int... values) {
    return new CashDrawer(this.twenties + values[0],
            this.tens + values[1],
            this.fives + values[2],
            this.twos + values[3],
            this.ones + values[4]
            );
}
\end{lstlisting}
```

And you will get a pretty-printed listing with reserved words etc. highlighted.

You probably don't want the `\begin{figure}[h]`¹ that you're doing. That will force everything to fit on one page and if it doesn't fit on the current page will put it at the top of the next page or on a page by itself.

**What you think you want to do but really don't**

As for why what you're doing is producing the output that it is, when something is longer than the width of a line, the excess will, by default, extend into the right margin.

The simplest approach for your case would be to replace the `\includegraphics` line with:

```
\makebox[\linewidth]
   {\hss\includegraphics[width=1.3\textwidth]{file.png}\hss}
```

The `\hss` is short for horizontal stretch and shrink. This, combined with `\makebox[\linewidth]` puts the graphic in a box the width of a line² and then centers it allowing it to extend into the margins.

**Plus, a free tip**

With screen shots, smaller is always better. I would recommend against doing a full-screen screen shot, but instead, make the window as small as possible while still showing all relevant information and then take a screen shot of just that window.

---

1. A common beginner's mistake is to think that every `tabular` needs to be wrapped in `table` and every graphic in `figure`, but this is not the case.
2. Note that this particular construction will work fine inside the `figure` environment but will give an overful `\hbox` error outside a `figure` environment since it would have the paragraph indentation before it. In general, I recommend wrapping displayed graphics in a custom environment, like:

   ```
    \NewDocumentEnvironment{displaypic}{}
        {\begin{center}}
        {\end{center}}
    ...
    \begin{displaypic}
    \includegraphics[width=.5\linewidth]{mypic.png}
    \end{displaypic}
   ```

Comment: Thanks Don, this helped! I so it went with 
`\makebox[\linewidth]    {\hspace*{-1cm}\hss\includegraphics[width=1.8\textwidth]{Image.png}\hss}`

I needed the full screenshot aka the PNG file for the task needed, but thanks for all the other useful information!